# ¿En la Shell, cómo obtener la suma de una variable de un archivo CSV en base a dos parámetros?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, línea-de-comandos

Resulta que tengo un archivo CSV sobre el covid y quiero averiguar quiénes han recibido más PCR, si los hombres y las mujeres. La variable SEXO contiene si el individuo es hombre o mujer, y la variable PCR contiene los PCR realizados por cada individuo. Sin embargo, no sé cómo podría calcular esto. Estoy pensando que igual tendré que hacer un condicional `if/else` para indicar que si el individuo es hombre sume los PCR realizados y si es mujer los sume por otro lado, para al final comparar quiénes han recibido más. En caso de ser así, tengo que indagar más sobre la utilización del condicional if ya que aún no sé utilizarlo muy bien en shell. En caso de haber otra manera de hacerlo, no se me ocurre nada.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora para localizar los datos que necesito del archivo CSV:

`cat covid19.csv | cut -d "," -f4,8 | head -15`

Donde los primeros 15 resultados serían los siguientes:

```
SEXE,PCR
Home,2
Dona,0
Dona,1
Dona,0
Dona,1
Dona,0
Dona,0
Home,0
Home,0
Home,0
Home,1
Home,0
Dona,1
Dona,5
```

¿Alguien sabría cómo podría calcular la suma de los PCR para los hombres y para las mujeres? No sé si en este caso se podrá utilizar `sed` o `awk` pero **no me está permitido utilizarlos en este ejercicio, así que sería buscar otra alternativa**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si instalas datamash, podrías hacerlo con:

```
$ datamash -Hst , -g 1 sum 2 < covid.csv
```

Resultando, de un archivo csv tipo:

```
$ cat covid.csv
SEXE,PCR
Home,2
Dona,0
Dona,1
Dona,0
Dona,1
Dona,0
Dona,0
Home,0
Home,0
Home,0
Home,1
Home,0
Dona,1
Dona,5
```

Entonces al correr el comando de `datamash`, obtienes:

```
$ datamash -Hst , -g 1 sum 2 < covid.csv
GroupBy(SEXE),sum(PCR)
Dona,8
Home,3
```

Donde:

- -H indica que la primera línea son los headers
- -s indica que el archivo viene no ordenado
- `-t ,` indica que el separador son las comas
- `-g 1` indica que se va a agrupar basado en el primer campo
- `sum 2` indica que, de lo agrupado, se va a sumar la segunda columna

Esto es suponiendo que el archivo es como lo describí anteriormente. Independientemente del archivo, sustituye el "1" por la columna que contenga el género, y el "2" por la que tenga los datos numéricos de los PCR.

### Actualización

Se me ocurrió otra manera con un script y usando únicamenta bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

archivo=./covid.csv
declare -A info=(
    [Home]=0
    [Dona]=0
)

shopt -s lastpipe
tail -n +2 $archivo \
  | \
while
    IFS=,
    read sexo numero
do
    curr_val=${info[$sexo]}
    info[$sexo]=$(( curr_val + numero ))
done

echo ${!info[@]}
echo ${info[@]}
```

Resultando en:

```
$ ./group_sum
Home Dona
3 8
```

En el script, dentro del `while`, supuse que la primer variable después de la coma es el sexo, y la segunda es el número. En caso de no ser así, asigna las el nombre de las variables según su posición correspidiente en tu archivo csv.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me ha servido a la perfección utilizando `datamash` !! Probaré también con la segunda opción que me ha proporcionado!! Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo haria algo como esto (feo, pero funciona):

```
temp=$( sed 's/,/ /' covid19.csv | while read blah numero; do temp=$(( $temp + $numero )); echo $temp; done | tail -n 1 )
echo salida: $temp
```

Hacer este tipo de cosas en bash es un poco enrevesado. te recomendaría mirar python.

Comment: Es que es una asignatura de programación en scripting que tengo y en un apartado de un ejercicio me piden eso así que tendré que apañármelas para tratar de conseguirlo. Encima no me permiten utilziar ni `sed` ni `awk` así que más trabas para hacer el ejercicio todavía. Independientemente de eso, gracias por el aporte!